# Is it OK to use soap to clean penis?

Tags: penis

I have something white dots on my penis. Is it OK to use soap to clean penis? Or what should you use to clean penis?

Comment: The answer is correct, there is no special soap for penis. It's nearly impossible to tell about the "white dots" without more details: when did they appear? Did you do something before the appeared? Where exactly are they located? Does it hurt when touching them? And more.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Totally agree. I answered on the assumption that the white dots were on the outside skin of the penis. Otherwise, soap will most likely not do any harm, but it will sting and burn a bit. In any case, see a dermatologist if the white dots keep recurring

Comment: About the white dots, have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hirsuties_coronae_glandis (caution, possible NSFW image)

Comment: The OP has "white dots" on his penis and everyone's talking about soap? WTF....

Comment: @CareyGregory Well, OP's question was whether if one can use soap and not about the white dots. I can't tell OP anything than visits dermatologist if the white dots stay. So yeah, that's why everyone talks about soap

Comment: If the soap stings, it's the wrong soap.  If the soap doesn't sting, you chose well.  Are you talking about the smegma that accumulates under the foreskin?  Gentle retraction while washing will help in that case.  However, a visit to your regular doctor would allow you to rule out a condition that would require medical treatment.  Don't worry about making this visit.  Doctors are used to examining genitals and diagnosing various conditions.